# Como pegar tag com javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

O meu site tem algumas imagens e quero que quando a pessoa clique em um botão, ele chame a função que vai "transformar" todas as imagens da tag `img` em:

```
display none;
```

Sem ter que pegar cada ID de uma imagem, quero algo como

```
document.querySelector("img");
```

E que este seletor pegue toda a tag `img`, tentei ser o mais claro possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter uma lista com todos os elementos HTML de uma determinada tag use a função [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), a mesma vai lhe retornar uma lista com todos os elementos da página

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Para pegar essa listagem e alterar a propriedade `display` para `none` use o código abaixo:

```
for (let image of document.getElementsByTagName("img")) {
   image.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado kkkk estava buscando errado.

Answer (score 2):

O método [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) irá retornar somente o *primeiro* elemento que satisfazer o seletor informado no primeiro argumento.

Se você quiser obter a lista completa de todos os elementos que satisfazem o seletor informado, você deverá utilizar o método [`document.querySelectoraAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), que retorna um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Com ela, você deve iterar sobre cada elemento para realizar as modificações individuais.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
  
  els.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<strong>Foo</strong>
<strong>Bar</strong>
<strong>Baz</strong>
<strong>Qux</strong>

<button>Remover</button>
```

Você também pode utilizar o método [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), que tem um suporte mais elevado. No entanto, acho o `querySelectorAll` mais conveniente.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, vou utilizar document.getElementsByTagName achei mais simples.